# Getting error at viewpost.php any one help me

Tags: php, mysql

> ```
> <?php
>     $reload = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?tpages=" . $tpages;
>     echo '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
>     if ($total_pages > 1) {
>         echo paginate($reload, $show_page, $total_pages);
>     }
>     echo "</ul></div>";
>     // display data in table
>
>     echo "<table class='imagetable'>";
>     echo "<thead><tr><th>Title</th> <th>Last Date</th><th>View Details</th></tr></thead>";
>     // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
>     for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
>         // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
>         if ($i == $total_results) {
>             break;
>         }
>
>         // echo out the contents of each row into a table
>         echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'title') . '</td>';
>         echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'date') . '</td>';
>       echo '<td><a href="' . mysql_result($result, $i, "viewpost.php"?id=<?php echo '$row[0]'?>) . '"></td>';
>         echo "</tr>";
>     }       
>     // close table>
> echo "</table>";
> // pagination
> ?>
> ```

Getting error at viewpost.php any one help me.

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\home\single.php on line 102

Comment: echo '<td><a href="' . mysql_result($result, $i, "viewpost.php"?id=<?php echo '$row[0]'?>) . '"></td>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what is it mean

```
mysql_result($result, $i, "viewpost.php"?id=<?php echo '$row[0]'?>)
```

to

```
mysql_result($result, $i, "columnname")."?id=".$row[0]);
```

Attempt #2

```
$pageId=mysql_result($result, $i, 'id');
echo '<td><a href="test.php?id='.$pageId.'"></td>';
```

Comment: i need to go to viewpost.php based on id

Comment: which page that could traverse?

Comment: viewpage.php wich contains display od data based on id

Comment: edited my post, use viewpage.php instead of test.php

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in the following line. Change

```
echo '<td><a href="' . mysql_result($result, $i, "viewpost.php"?id=<?php echo '$row[0]'?>) . '"></td>';
                                                              ^
```

to

```
echo '<td><a href="' . mysql_result($result, $i, "viewpost.php?id=$row[0]") . '"></td>';
                                                                  ^
```

Don't enclose the PHP inside single quotes like you have done in that line. Also the URL parameters also should be enclosed in the double quotes as it is also string. As you are using echo you don't need to specify PHP tags again in the same line.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\xampp\htdocs\home\single.php on line 103

Answer (score 0):

```
  echo '<td><a href="' . mysql_result($result, $i, "viewpost.php"?id=<?php echo '$row[0]'?>) . '"></td>';
```

I think the string that begins with viewpost.php needs to be turned into a string. At the moment you've got what looks like some cut and pasted inline PHP code where what you want is a string. This has the close tag for PHP in it and will not work.

What do you intend to pass to the mysql_result function? What's that `<?php echo '$row[0]'?>` supposed to do?